# ASP.NET Core WEB Api connect to JS

Tags: c#, asp.net, frontend

I'm on enter level with web dev, and i have very important question...
When I write application in ASP.NET MVC i can return HTML view and there is an idea to create frontend for my application.

But when I use asp.net core web api I just see JSON files in my browser. My endPoints return only JSON results... and my question is :

**How I can view this JSON files using HTML?**

What is the way to take this JSON Files ? In my WEB Api project i don't have any view folder or something like this... Can someone explain me how it works?

Comment: `asp.net core web api` that's the web api project template and does not have UI components such as Views with `.cshtml` extensions. While creating a project in .NET core, you need to make sure to select MVC project template instead of Web API.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ASP.NET MVC, actions return a View that is rendered into an HTML webpage.
In this case, the rendering is done on your back-end (your API server).

With ASP.NET Web API, actions return data.
You'll need to write Javascript that makes a request to your API and renders the resulting data into HTML so that it can be viewed.
In this case, the rendering is done on your front-end (your user's browser).

Comment: I should for example fetch data?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is. Suppose you have a json like this:

```
public class JsonDetail  
{  
    public string FirstName {  
        get;  
        set;  
    }  
    public string LastName {  
        get;  
        set;  
    }  
}  

// output from asp.net core c#
var json = @ "{  
    'FirstName': 'Peter', 'LastName': 'Smith'  
}";  

// then use Newtonsoft.json
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <JsonDetail> (json);
```

Now, this model can be used in MVC.